# GCC does not generate debugger information when using -g, -ggdb, -g3, or -ggdb3

Tags: c, gcc, debugging

I'm using GCC 4.4.1 and GDB 7.0-ubuntu on [Ubuntu 9.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_9.10_.28Karmic_Koala.29) (Karmic Koala). However, GCC won't generate debugger information when using any of the following switches: [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g), [-g3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-gvms), [-ggdb](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-ggdb), or [-ggdb3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-gvms).

So when I run the program with GDB, it’s as if there wasn’t any debugger information generated. I have created very simple test source files in a new, empty folder.

Here is one example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
     char    msg[4];

     // Allocate 4 bytes on the stack
     strcpy (msg, "Hello, World!");

     // Overflow
     printf ("%s\n", msg);
     return 0;
}
```

Here is my command line sequence:

```
gcc -g ./mytest.c -o mytest
gdb ./mytest
```

I have previously turned on MALLOC_CHECK_=1 in order to test the stack overflow problem in the code. And this works, so I get a stack trace. But the stack trace is no different whether I include the debug information or not. With the debugger information, I expected to see a line number of a file for where the problem occurred under GDB. However, this doesn't happen.

Comment: did you pass -gANYTHING to the linking command line?

Comment: post the command line that you use to compile your program, and the message you get that leads you to think that your exe has no debug information

Comment: Good question. Since its only linking to the standard libs, I just used: gcc -ggdb ./test.c -o test.o. To have debugger info included, am I required to compile and link in two steps?

Comment: Whoops. You just made an executable named test.o, if that.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. I ran the debugger on my computer. I had to add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to compile it though. I called the file `debugger.c`. Here are the steps:

```
gcc -g debugger.c
gdb a.out
```

which will start the debugger

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815
...
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Developer/stackoverflow/extern/a.out
Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff88040886 in __kill ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fff88040886 in __kill ()
#1  0x00007fff880e0e4f in __abort ()
#2  0x00007fff880d5693 in __chk_fail ()
#3  0x00007fff8802f851 in __strcpy_chk ()
#4  0x0000000100000f04 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff958) at debugger.c:9
(gdb)
```

But it seems like your problem isn't running the debugger, but getting the information where your code failed. You can use `backtrace` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
gcc -g test.c -o mytest
gdb mytest
```

Never call anything "test" - it clashes with a shell built in. and "test.o" would by convention be the name of an object file, not an executable.

Comment: Good points. But that doesn't solve the problem. Is there another reason this might happen?

Comment: @CJJ You still haven't said why you think the executable doesn't have debug information - what message are you getting that makes you think that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says you ran:

```
gcc -ggdb ./test.c -o test.o
```

That's probably not what you want.

```
gcc -ggdb -o mytest test.c
```

is likelier to be successful. If gdb ralphs on that then you have something wrong with your installation of gcc or gdb.